# Organising a client & server SPA/Node.js application

Tags: javascript

I am writing an application with a Node.js backend and a single-page web app front-end.

I am keeping the client and server logic in the same project for simplicity and speed of development.

I am considering how best to organise the artifacts.

The Node.js part is straightforward because it doesn't need to go through a battery of pre-processors (transpilation, minification, concatenation etc).

The front-end needs to be transformed per the above, and I guess placed in a `dist` folder.

The current hierarchy of files is like so:

```
my-app
 - src
   - client
   - server
```

Should I put the dist folder for the client artifacts under src/client?

Has anyone tried this and found problems with this approach?

I am using Heroku (a deployment system that uses git).

Committing the built artifacts for the client feels wrong, but if I want to deploy it by pushing to Heroku I think I need to commit them. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you using a templating language? That affects what sort of layout you should consider. And yes, you should either commit the `dist` folder, or have a task generate it using the `npm postinstall` hook

Comment: Client is react/redux. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah, that makes it clearer. I would personally put the `dist` at the root, i.e. `my-app/dist`, that seems to be the convention, especially since `dist` is _not_ `src`.

Comment: Thank you. I had that inkling too. Do you have any experience with the Heroku part of my question?

Comment: I work a lot with heroku, committing the `dist` folder makes your life a lot easier. It's very possible to avoid doing so, but the downside is very minimal and the upside is much easier debugging. I just added another reason to commit the folder in my answer. I think you'll find that argument very convincing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question, as is, invites opinionated answers, so I'll start by saying this is by no means the *only* way to go, but in my opinion, it is the easiest to work with and makes the most sense.

The production client code, after pre-processing, should be located in `my-app/dist` or `my-app/dst`, which could either mean `distribution` or `destination`, depending on how you look at it. Either way, my recommendation is to *commit* this folder, as it saves you a lot of hassle debugging remotely.

For example, if your code works locally but not remotely, using something like the `postinstall` hook to generate your `dist` folder adds yet another suspect to check when trying to determine what the issue is with your program.

Another advantage of committing the `dist` folder is it allows you to specify all the packages you use for your build process as `devDependencies` rather than `dependencies`. This is a *huge* plus, and makes deployment a lot faster, as well as less memory usage on your heroku process.

That being said, I still recommend (as you already probably plan to do) using an automated `watch` task to build your `dist` folder for ease of development, even if you decide you don't want to use that same build process remotely and opt for committing the `dist` directory instead. You could add that as a custom `npm` command, e.g. `npm run build` and have that invoke your `gulp` task.

One last thing. For those of you using templating languages like `pug` or `dust` or `ejs` instead of a framework like `react` or `angular`, I recommend determining whether you can run any of your templates to build static HTML files that will be served in production.

If not, you should at least compile your templates (not to be confused with running them) by following the recommendations provided by your particular templating language. Typically, they'll suggest using their command line utility to generate the compiled templates, so that they don't have to be compiled every time they're invoked in production. This will make your node.js server respond faster to requests at the expense of using more memory to cache the compiled templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to go this route, I would edit nodejs app.js/index.js to serve static file and point the directory to `dist/`. 
Also, you would need to tell express to forward all non-api requests to the frontend.